# what is the best software for drawing mechanical mechanism?

Tags: publications, graphics, software

I want a software which I can use to draw mechanisms like this picture:

[image]

Update:
the author told me that : "the figure was made in Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator by tracing the hand-drawn kinematic diagrams."

Comment: where does this image come from? have you asked authors?

Comment: this is from paper "Design of Multi-Grip Patterns Prosthetic Hand with Single Actuator" .. i did not ask the author

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This type of request is usually something authors will gladly address. Since this images comes [from recent paper (2018)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8345188), you should write to corresponding authors or journal editor, asking how this image was produced. In fact, providing such information is part of obligation when people publish work, your request will not be unusual at all.

Comment: I thought it is inappropriate to ask the author about how he drew his pictures. thank yo for your respond I will try to contact with the author.

Comment: @ndpl the idea of publication is to allow people check your work. Tondo that people need to know your methods

Comment: @ndpl Do you expect author to refuse OP?